# ¿Hacer una consulta en SQL SERVER que me muestre la ultima fecha en que se registro cada producto, pero que sea de un almacen en especifico?

Tags: sql-server-2014, sql-server-2017

Buen día

Tengo la siguiente tabla con estos datos de ejemplo:

> ```
> CREATE TABLE productos_2020 (
>                     id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
>                     producto_id INT,
>                     nombre_producto NVARCHAR(30),
>                     almacen NVARCHAR(30),
>                     fecha DATETIME NOT NULL
>         );
>
>
>
>   INSERT INTO productos_2020 (producto_id, nombre_producto, almacen, fecha)
>         VALUES 
>         (8,'MANZANA','TMDB','2020-09-20 00:00:00'),
>         (8,'MANZANA','TMPPIC','2020-09-15 21:00:00'),
>         (8,'MANZANA','TMDB','2020-09-16 22:00:00'),
>         (8,'MANZANA','TMDB','2020-09-16 22:01:00'),
>         (8,'MANZANA','TMPPIC','2020-09-18 21:00:00'),
>         (1,'UVA','TMDB','2020-09-15 21:00:00'),
>         (1,'UVA','TMDB','2020-09-15 21:15:00'),
>         (1,'UVA','TMPPIC','2020-09-15 21:15:00'),
>         (1,'UVA','TMDB','2020-09-15 21:15:20'),
>         (1,'UVA','TMDB','2020-09-15 21:15:00'),
>         (1,'UVA','TMC','2020-09-15 21:15:00'),
>         (1,'UVA','TMAG','2020-09-15 21:16:00'),
>         (1,'UVA','TMAG','2020-09-15 21:17:00'),
>         (1,'UVA','TMAG','2020-09-15 21:17:01'),
>         (2,'NARANJA','TMDB','2020-09-15 21:00:00'),
>         (2,'NARANJA','TMPPIC','2020-09-18 23:00:00'),
>         (2,'NARANJA','TMDB','2020-09-16 21:00:00'),
>         (2,'NARANJA','TMPPIC','2020-09-17 23:00:00'),
>         (2,'NARANJA','TMDB','2020-09-19 21:00:00'),
>         (2,'NARANJA','TMDB','2020-09-19 21:00:01'),
>         (2,'NARANJA','TMPPIC','2020-09-18 23:00:10'),
>         (2,'NARANJA','TMDB','2020-09-18 23:01:00'),
>         (3,'PERA','TMAG','2020-09-15 22:00:00'),
>         (3,'PERA','TMDB','2020-09-16 21:00:10'),
>         (3,'PERA','TMPPIC','2020-09-16 21:30:10'),
>         (3,'PERA','TMAG','2020-09-14 22:00:00'),
>         (3,'PERA','TMDB','2020-09-16 21:10:00'),
>         (3,'PERA','TMAG','2020-09-15 22:00:00'),
>         (3,'PERA','TMDB','2020-09-16 21:00:00'),
>         (3,'PERA','TMPPIC','2020-09-16 21:31:10')
>       ;
> ```

Lo que necesito es mostrar la última fecha que se registro cada uno de los productos (Sin repetir el producto), siempre y cuando sean del almacen "TMDB", si la ultima fecha del producto no es del almacen "TMDB" que no lo muestre.

Muchas gracias y saludos, espero me puedan ayudar

Comment: SQL server 2014 o 2017? Intentaste algo para hacer esa consulta? Si es así, falló? Esta muy bien incluir toda la info de la fuente de datos y los datos de prueba, pero siempre sera valioso incluir el esfuerzo personal para resolver el problema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya encontré la solución, y es de la siguiente manera:

```
with R as (
    select 
    *, row_number() over(partition by nombre_producto order by fecha desc, almacen desc) as rn 
    from productos_2020 
) 
select 
producto_id as 'ID DE PRODUCTO', nombre_producto as 'producto', 
almacen as 'ALMACEN DONDE SE ENCUENTRA', 
FORMAT(fecha, 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss') as 'FECHA DE RESGUARDO' 
from R 
where rn = 1 and almacen='TMDB';
```

Espero y pueda servirle a varias personas

saludos y gracias.

Comment: Creo que vale la pena pulir un poco tu respuesta. Sugiero no añadir todo el script que ya está en la pregunta, en cambio poner la consulta en más de una sola línea para que sea más fácil de entender y explicar cómo funciona la solución. Gracias por el aporte y que bueno que pudiste responder tu propia pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer uso de la funcion `max` para obtener la fecha maxima y `group by` para agrupar los registros de `sql server`.

Ejemplo:

```
select producto_id, nombre_producto, almacen, max(fecha) as UltimaFecha from productos_2020 WHERE almacen='TMDB' group by producto_id, nombre_producto, almacen
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por contestar, pero esa consulta me devuelve todos los registros, lo que necesito es que la consulta me devuelva la ultima fecha de cada producto, siempre y cuando sean del almacén 'TMDB', si no, que no me muestre el registro de ese producto.

Comment: habia un detalle ya lo modifique se me quedo la fecha en el group by. solo hay que quitar la fecha y quedaría como  WHERE almacen='TMDB' group by producto_id, nombre_producto, almacen

Comment: Agradezco muchísimo tu ayuda, pero lo que que pasa es que este código que me envías me manda la ultima fecha de cada producto del almacén 'TMDB'. Lo que necesito, es que me mande la última fecha de los 4 productos que hay. Por ejemplo en el caso de la UVA, la fecha que es mas reciente es esta: (1,'UVA','TMAG','2020-09-15 21:17:01'), pero como puedes observar no es de la instalación 'TMDB' asi que no me la debe de mostrar. es decir el producto UVA no lo debe mostrar